# Azure Publish Profile Download is disabled

Tags: azure-web-app-service, publish-profiles

I've created a an App Service using the Azure portal and wanted to download the Publish Profile (to import that into Visual Studio). But the download button is disabled. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is it visible in classic portal?

Comment: Oink!? Yes it is, and I could download it.
I could even import it into VS. Crazy

Thank you for this suggestion. Pity that it's not working on the new portal. I was able to do it a while ago. Must have done something to make it angry. :-)

Answer (score 28):

**My Scenario**:- I'm using Visual Studio 2022 community edition. I was trying to publish the website to the 'Azure App Service' but it was throwing 'connected to the remote computer but could not authorize the remote server returned an error 401 unauthorized' error.
I realized that it was due to the publish profile and when i went to the azure portal i saw that 'Download publish profile' was disabled.

**Fix:-**
Below are the steps that solved the issue for me.

- Select Azure Web app which you have created.
- Under settings --> Configuration --> "General settings" -->turned off "Basic Auth Publishing Credentials" --> Save
- Navigate back to "Overview" --> Restart webapp.
- Navigate back to settings--> Configuration-->"General Settings" -->turned on "Basic Auth Publishing Credentials". --> Save
- Finally, I restarted the web app and "Download publish profile" appeared for me
- Once it was enabled in the azure portal, when i published website by clicking 'Publish' button, I was also able to successfully publish my web app from Visual Studio.

**Somehow there might be a glitch when new webapp is created.**

[image]

Comment: I was initially skeptical about this solution. but I gave it a shot anyway. To my surprise, it actually did the trick. I don't know how or why, but it works.

Comment: This method is effective; I encountered the same issue, and employing this trick proved to be beneficial.

Comment: Just worked for me as well.

Comment: Strange that the correct answer to this is showing 7 years later. I had answered this in another forum but forgot how to fix it again ;( and this answer just helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Wow.... 6 years and still this bug exists! Solution worked, thanks

Comment: Interesting that so many people are running into this issue recently as evidenced by the dates of the comments and replies. I too ran into this issue upon creating a new App Service. Our Azure DevOps pipelines were failing to deploy to the App Service with a 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. After performing the above steps. everything now works. New bug in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a February 2024 version of the solution to this nonsense, it might have updated as recently they did some changes aroudn kudu deployment.

- Select Azure Web app which you have created.
- Under settings | Configuration | "General settings", Ensure that *both* SCM Basic Auth Publishing *and* FTP Basic Auth Publishing are "ON". --> Save
- Navigate back to "Overview" --> STOP web app.
- (Publishing Profile should be come available now)
- Restart your application

Comment: Yep, just done that and worked for me

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Were these defaulted to enabled before? This must be the Azure random change of the month.

Comment: I believe the SCM Basic Auth is relatively new and related to the move to Kudu deployment. I'm basing this assumption on some patch notes I saw for the azure cli around deployment.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason, in first attempt it's not working for me. But when I tried to do on/off 3-4 times and did restart, then I could download the publish profile.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it is available on the dashboard of the new portal. You need to hover over your function app tile and go into the menu as seen in the photo.

[image: Publish Profile on dashboard tile]